# Issue when displaying a thumbnail using Thumbnailutils

Tags: android, android-imageview, thumbnails

I'm using this code to get a thumbnail from a full size image path:

```
imagenThumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathImagen), 320, 320);
```

The problem is that when i use an imageview to display the thumbnail it is displayed the thumbnail rotated 90 degrees to the right. The image has been taken in vertical mode but i don't know why it is displayed rotated.

Any suggestion will be welcome.

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: same to me, have you solved somehow?

Answer (score 2):

```
            ImageView iv;
            iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            int THUMBSIZE = 64;

            // rotate bmpThumbImage
            Bitmap bmpThumbImage = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileUri.getPath()), THUMBSIZE, THUMBSIZE);
            iv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            matrix.postRotate(90);
            bmpThumbImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmpThumbImage, 0, 0, bmpThumbImage.getWidth(),
                    bmpThumbImage.getHeight(), matrix, true);
            iv.setImageBitmap(bmpThumbImage);
```

[How display thumbnail of video the same view of camera?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22883712/how-display-thumbnail-of-video-the-same-view-of-camera)

Comment: what if you don't know the initial orientation of the image?

Comment: I am not facing this issue on every Android device. How do I know when I have to rotate bitmap by 90? Happening to selected devices.